# Unable to alert success message after function executes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to get an alert of `"Thank you for your enquiry!"` after the function successfully executes and is sent to the database. My codes are as follows:

```
function addenquiry() {

    Texttitle = $("#Texttitle").val();
    Textenquiry = $("#Textenquiry").val();

    if (validate()) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = serverURL() + "/addenquiry.php";
        url += "?userid=" + userid + "&Texttitle=" + Texttitle + "&Textenquiry=" + Textenquiry;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                addEnquiry(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function addEnquiry(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    if (arr[0].result == 1) {
        alert("Thank You for your enquiry!")
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry please try again");
    }

}
```

Not sure where i have gone wrong, the title and message is successfully recorded in the database but i am not getting the alert, hope to receive some guidance and help from someone. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of XMLHttpRequest, check out fetch, it's supported in most modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Does that mean XMLHttpRequest would not work in my case?

Comment: No, sorry. XMLHttpRequest should work perfectly fine. I'm just suggesting using fetch instead of it.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, thanks! However, do you have any idea of where i have gone wrong because i can't seem to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I don't know. Try logging the response to make sure that `arr[0].result` is equal to `1`

Comment: Most browsers have a debug view.